# Select combinations of two columns in a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that looks like this

[image]

In this table I have to filter my select query with a where clause with four particular combinations of tp1 and tp2.
 I want to select data based on (tp1= A and tp2 = A) and (tp1=B and tp2 = C). I think I might have to use case statements in the where clause but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: you mean `where (tp1= 'A' and tp2 = 'A') or (tp1='B' and tp2 = 'C')` ?

Comment: You should edit your question with queries that you have tried and explain how it (they) do not work.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
WHERE (tp1 = 'A' and tp2 = 'A') OR (tp1 = 'B' and tp2 = 'C')
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I already tried this and it didn't work. But it turns out my query has some issues that is why it didn't work. I have to work on my query. Anyways thank you for your answer.